# Starting with AZURE VPN. IPSEC as method and Cisco 2611 router (4.x vpn client)

Tags: azure, ipsec, azure-vpn

I'm starting with Azure's VPN network.
I'm little bit confused about site-to-site and point-to-point methods.

What I need to do is, connect to a remote server that runs some SIP & H323 PBX server. The cisco router is used as a FXO/FXS lines/phone gateway.

I mean this cisco router is not used as router only as a H323 gateway, is like a remote client connecting trough a VPN and running a softphone.

So.. client-to-client is the easy method.. or is site to site ( I don't have any other device or host in my router so is not a remote site is only one terminal)

The thing with this router is the IOs version (12.2) a little bit older. It runs IPSEC client 4.X.. So it will work ?

Test first witha IPSEC in a PC first is a good idea I think

Ideas & comments are welcome !!!

Best Regards!!
Frank

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the model (2611). In general though, if this box is really acting as an endpoint (client or server), you have two choices:

1. Connect from 2611 directly to the virtual machine (VIP) without using Azure VPN. Of course you will need to ensure the connection is secure.
2. Create an Azure VPN gateway and establish a S2S VPN tunnel between your network and the Azure virtual network hosting your VM. Azure uses standard IPsec/IKE VPN (for route-based VPN, you will need IKEv2, policy-based VPN uses IKEv1).

Either option should work. Point-to-site VPN will not work for you though. Point-to-site requires a Windows machine as a VPN client connecting to Azure.

Please let us know if you have any questions.

Thanks,

Yushun [MSFT]